# How to send a HTTPS POST request to a JavaScript created login form using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, python-requests

How can I send a POST request to login to a website using the requests library?
The main url does not contain any login forms, but when clicked on a button a form appears (which I think is done via JavaScript)

Comment: inspect the source code for a `<form>...</form>` and send POST to the `action` attribute value

Comment: Should i find this tag when the form is shown?

Comment: yes if you inspect the generated source it should be there, and if not look on the network tab to see if it's sending a POST to a URL because it could also use AJAX and not need a form element

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the requests library you have to find the post request action URL then send the user and pass credentials accordingly

```
payload = {'nameOfUserNameInput': 'USERNAME', 'nameOfPasswordInput': 'PASSWORD'}
url = 'http://www.example.com/action_url'
requests.post(url, data=payload)
```